# Call measure how far you dragged in Android

Tags: java, android

I made an application running in the background, and I want to add a function to measure the slide on the screen. I'll leave you the code for both, and someone can help me. I'm a beginner and I've been looking all over trying to solve this without results.

***I know the post is too long, but I did not know how to shorten it so you can understand it.***

**The code for running the application in the background**

App.java

```
package com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.app.Application;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.os.Build;


public class App extends Application {
public static final String CHANNEL_ID = "exampleServiceChannel";

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    createNotificationChannel();
}

private void createNotificationChannel() {
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel serviceChannel = new NotificationChannel(
                CHANNEL_ID,
                "Example Service Channel",
                NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT
        );

        NotificationManager manager = 
getSystemService(NotificationManager.class);
        manager.createNotificationChannel(serviceChannel);
    }
}
}
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample">

<application
    android:name=".App"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service android:name=".ExampleService" />
</application>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>

</manifest>
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
tools:context="com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample.MainActivity">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/edit_text_input"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Input" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="startService"
    android:text="Start Service" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="stopService"
    android:text="Stop Service" />

</LinearLayout>
```

ExampleService.java

```
package com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat;

import static com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample.App.CHANNEL_ID;


public class ExampleService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String input = intent.getStringExtra("inputExtra");

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this,
            0, notificationIntent, 0);

    Notification notification = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, 
 CHANNEL_ID)
            .setContentTitle("Example Service")
            .setContentText(input)
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_android)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build();

    startForeground(1, notification);

    return START_NOT_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
}
```

MainActivity.java

```
package com.codinginflow.foregroundserviceexample;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private EditText editTextInput;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    editTextInput = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_input);
}

public void startService(View v) {
    String input = editTextInput.getText().toString();

    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    serviceIntent.putExtra("inputExtra", input);

    ContextCompat.startForegroundService(this, serviceIntent);
}

public void stopService(View v) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(this, ExampleService.class);
    stopService(serviceIntent);
}
}
```

**Code for sliding measurement**

```
Point p1;
Point p2;

View view = new View(this);

view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
   public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
     if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        p1 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());
     else if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        p2 = new Point((int) event.getX(), (int) event.getY());

     return false;
  }
});
```

Can someone call me this code in my app?

Comment: Please put the code, or short, easily understood extracts, in-line rather than as links to external text.

Comment: Now it is better?

Comment: Yes, and thank you.

Comment: Yes, but unfortunately not many have seen the message or no one wants to help me ...